# Angular js. Как создать новый массив в фильтре?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

В таблице данных вызывается модал при клике на изображение. В модале выводятся данные из выбранной строки. Если воспользоваться фильтром поиска, то формируется новая таблица. И если в этой (новой) таблице вызвать модал кликом на изображение, то в модале выводятся данные из предыдущей (а не из новой таблицы, т.е. данные в модале не соответствуют выбранной строке). Как создать новый массив данных, чтобы выбор атрибутов происходил из нового массива данных при вызове модала? Пример на [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JvRIoFBvUxVPMk10cfR7?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search ..." ng-model="searchCity">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="searchCity = ''">Press to clear</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<td>{{d.customerNumber}}</td>
<td ng-click="vm.open($index)"><img class="img-size" ng-src="{{d.image}}"></td>
<td>{{d.Country}}</td>
<td>{{d.City}}</td>
<td>{{d.Population}}</td>
```

**JS**

```
$http.get('dataset.json').then(function(x) {
        vm.datasets = x.data;
    });


vm.open = function(index) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            scope: $scope,//
            templateUrl: "modalContent.html",
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                index: function() {
                    return index;
                },
                datasets: function () {
                    return vm.datasets
                }
            }
        });
  };

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, datasets, index) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.datasets = datasets;
    $scope.selected = {
        item: vm.datasets[index]
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему лучше решать с другой стороны: вместо передачи индекса и получения по нему элемента, можно сразу передавать элемента.

[**Пример на Plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fp6nHHVwzuhuPyUWSWBj?p=preview)

```
<td ng-click="vm.open(d)">
```

---

```
resolve: {
    item: function() {
        return item;
    },
```

---

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, datasets, item) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.datasets = datasets;
    $scope.selected = {
        item: item
    };
}
```

Comment: оба варианта рабочие, выбрал второй. Всем спасибо за подсказку!)

Answer (score 0):

**app.js**

```
datasets: function () {
    return vm.datasets
}
```

заменить на

```
datasets: function () {
    return vm.filteredDatasets
}
```

**index.html**

```
ng-repeat="d in vm.datasets | filter:searchCity"
```

заменить на

```
ng-repeat="d in (vm.filteredDatasets = (vm.datasets | filter:searchCity))"
```

Comment: и этот вариант работает!)